# Segfaults on commented lines :

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve a problem on Codechef. I've posted about this before but am doing in completely differently.

http://www.codechef.com/problems/STEPUP#

The idea of the problem is to determine whether or not the desired situation arises for the given testcase. 
A desired situation is when every vertex has a higher indirection than the vertices that are connected to it. Ie. if a->b, F(b) should be > F(a). If this isn't possible for the given setup, output is IMPOSSIBLE. If not, output the minimum value of F(x) for the vertex X with maximum indirection such that it holds for all other vertices. 
I haven't tried to print the output for the possible cases yet.

INPUT FORMAT:

First line of input contains a number t, the number of test cases.

Each test case contain starts with two space seperated integers N and M, denoting the number of vertices and the number of edges in the graph respectively.

Each of the following M lines contain two space seperated integers a b denoting an edge from vertex a to vertex b.

There can be multiple edges between two vertices a and b.
For eg.,

```
2

2 2

1 2

2 1

3 2

1 2

1 3
```

OUTPUT should be:

IMPOSSIBLE

2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct Node{
 int val;
 struct Node* next;
};

int indirection[10001];//indirection[a] holds count. What vertex it holds count OF is     given by list[a].val;

int main()
{
 int testcases, num_vertices, num_edges, a,b,c,d,e;
 scanf("%d", &testcases);
 while(testcases--)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&num_vertices, &num_edges);
        struct Node *list[num_vertices];//array of pointers to node
        int h;
        struct Node * ptr;
        for(h=1;h<=num_vertices;h++)
           {
            list[h]=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            list[h]->val=0;
           }
        memset(indirection,0,10001);
        for(e=0;e<10001;e++)
            printf("Indirection[e]=%d \n",indirection[e]);

        a=1;
        while(a<=num_edges)
        {
            printf("messge printing for the %dth time\n",a);
             scanf("%d %d",&b,&c);
             printf("Message recd %d \n",indirection[c]);
             if(indirection[c]==0)   
                { 
                    printf("entered case1\n");
                     list[a]->val=c;
                     printf("S\n");
                       //Segfaults here
                    list[a]->next->val=b;
                     printf("SS\n");
                     indirection[a]=1;
                     ptr=list[a]->next;
                     printf("SSS \n");
                     printf("case1\n");
                }
             else
                 {  printf("entered case2\n");
                    indirection[c]++;
                     //segfaults here if i comment out the previous one
                     ptr->next->val=b;
                     printf("case2\n");
                     ptr=ptr->next;

                }
            a++;
         }

         int tra,i;
         struct Node *ptr1,*ptrnext;
         for(i=1;i<=num_edges;i++)
         {
            ptr1=list[i];
            ptrnext=list[i]->next;
            {
                if (indirection[ptr1->val]<indirection[ptrnext->val])
                     {   printf("IMPOSSIBLE");
                         break;
                      }

               else
                    {   
                        ptr1=ptrnext;
                        ptrnext=ptrnext->next;
                    }


            }

          }
          free(list);
    }
}
```

The 2 statements where I've mentioned a segfault in comments are just before the (I think) questionable statements. If I remove the first, segfault at the second. If I remove both, segfault ANYWAY.

Still trying to solve this problem so I can move forward with the next one. Thanks!

Comment: `list[a]->next->val` is a bad idea since you don't prevent `NULL` dereference, you must check that `list[a]->next != NULL` before dereferencing it.

Comment: wait a minute, does this even compile? How can you do `struct Node *list[num_vertices];`?  You can't pass a non-const variable as an array size.

Comment: @Daniel  `struct Node *list[num_vertices];` is a variable length array - introduced 15 years ago in C99.  In C11 (and before) it is optional.

Comment: @iharob where do I add the NULL check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num_vertices` treated as if it is 1 based rather than 0 based

```
    struct Node *list[num_vertices];//array of pointers to node
    int h;
    struct Node * ptr;

    // for(h=1;h<=num_vertices;h++)
    for(h=0;h<num_vertices;h++)

       {
        list[h]=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        list[h]->val=0;
       }
```

`next` field is not initialized as answered by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27554409/2410359)

```
       {
        list[h]=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        list[h]->val = 0;
        list[h]->next = something_maybe_NULL();
       }
```

---

Suggest simpler `malloc()` style

```
        list[h] = malloc(sizeof *(list[h]));
```

Comment: Thank you. I've made the mallocs hard so that I understand the nitty gritty of pointers completely. What can I set for the value of list[h]->next?

Comment: I would need to study your code more, but maybe `list[h]->next = list[h+1]` is needed.  Something like `for(h=0;h<num_vertices;h++)  { list[h]=malloc(sizeof *(list[h])); list[h]->val=0; list[h]->next=NULL; } for(h=1;h<num_vertices;h++)  { list[h-1]->next = list[h];}`

Answer (score 1):

Your code segfaults because you create an array of `struct Node*` and allocate memory for them, but you never set the `next` pointer of each `Node`. So each `Node`'s `next` pointer is just pointing somewhere random in memory and segfaults when you try to access it.

I think your design is just wrong. If you are trying to make a linked list of nodes (as suggested by the presence of a next pointer), you don't need to create an array to hold the nodes at all.

Comment: What can I set Node->next to?

Comment: @tvishwa107 any allocated node

Comment: I could create some random node just for the purpose of making everything point here?

Comment: @tvishwa107 see my edit to my answer. Why do you have a next pointer if it's just pointing to something random? Point it to the next thing in the list. Then you won't need an array and your other problem of accessing the array as if it's 1-indexed is solved for free.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to make an adjacency list for each node that contains which vertices have an edge into it. Eg. if a->c, b->c, c's list will contain a and b. 
That's why I'm using an array. If there's a better way to do this I'm open to suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

I analyzed all your code and found several problems in it, these problems indicate mainly that you don't understand pointers

1. Arrays are `0`-index based

   ```
   /* if you declare, struct list[size];
    * index goes from 0 ti szie - 1
    */
   for (h = 1 ; h <= num_vertices ; h++)
   {
   ```
2. You never initialize `node->next` pointer

   ```
   /* You should initialize the next node to null. */
   list[h]->next = NULL;
   ```
3. Your `memset` is wrong, `sizeof(int) != 1`

   ```
   /* memset(indirection, 0, 10001); wrong */
   memset(indirection, 0, 10001 * sizeof(int));
   ```
4. You don't check for overflow when accessing the `indirection` array

   ```
   /* this is very unsafe, you don't check c */
   printf("Message recd %d \n", indirection[c]);
   ```
5. You dereference `node->next` without checking for `NULL`

   ```
   /* don't dereference list[a]->next without checking . 
    * list[a]->next->val (wrong) 
    */
   next = list[a]->next;
   if (next != NULL)
       next->val = b;
   ```
6. You `free` `list`, it is an array not a pointer so you can't call `free` on it, however, you should `free` its elements, since they are pointers to valid `malloc`ed memory

   ```
   for (i = 0 ; i < num_vertices ; i++)
       free(list[i]);
   ```

Here is a version of your code with this issues fixed, I don't know if your algorithm works, but the code has at least 6 fewer errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
/* no need for typedef, since you declare as struct Node */
struct Node
{
    int          val;
    struct Node* next;
};

int indirection[10001];//indirection[a] holds count. What vertex it holds count OF is     given by list[a].val;

int main()
{
    int testcases, num_vertices, num_edges, a, b, c;

    printf("input testcase: ");
    scanf("%d", &testcases);
    while (testcases--)
    {
        printf("input testcase num_vertices and num_edges: ");
        scanf("%d %d",&num_vertices, &num_edges);

        int          h;
        struct Node *list[num_vertices]; // array of pointers to node
        struct Node *ptr;

        /* struct list[size];
            * index goes from 0 ti szie - 1
            */
        for (h = 0 ; h < num_vertices ; h++)
        {
            /* If this is plain C you don't need the cast (struct Node *) */
            list[h]      = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            list[h]->val = 0;
            /* You should initialize the next node to null. */
            list[h]->next = NULL;
        }
        /* memset(indirection, 0, 10001); wrong */
        memset(indirection, 0, 10001 * sizeof(int));

        /* What, you dont believe all values are 0? */
        /* for(e = 0 ; e < 10001 ; e++)
            printf("Indirection[e] = %d\n",indirection[e]); */

        /* arrays go from 0 ti size - 1 */
        a = 0;
        while (a < num_edges)
        {
            printf("messge printing for the %dth time\n", a);

            printf("input b and c: ");
            scanf("%d %d", &b, &c);

            if (c < 10001)
            {
                /* this is very unsafe, you don't check c */
                printf("Message recd %d \n", indirection[c]);
                if (indirection[c]==0)
                {
                    struct Node *next;
                    printf("entered case1\n");

                    list[a]->val = c;
                    printf("S\n");

                    // Segfaults here
                    /* don't dereference list[a]->next without checking . */
                    next = list[a]->next;
                    if (next != NULL)
                        next->val = b;
                    printf("SS\n");

                    indirection[a] = 1;
                    ptr            = list[a]->next;

                    printf("SSS \n");
                    printf("case1\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("entered case2\n");
                    indirection[c]++;

                    //segfaults here if i comment out the previous one
                    ptr->next->val=b;

                    printf("case2\n");
                    ptr=ptr->next;
                }
                a++;
            }
        }

        int          i;
        struct Node *ptr1, *ptrnext;

        for(i = 0 ; i < num_edges ; i++) /* arrays go from 0 ti size - 1 */
        {
            ptr1 = list[i];
            if (ptr1 != NULL)
                ptrnext = ptr1->next;
            if ((ptr1 != NULL) && (ptrnext != NULL))
            {
                if (indirection[ptr1->val] < indirection[ptrnext->val])
                {
                    printf("IMPOSSIBLE");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ptr1    = ptrnext;
                    ptrnext = ptrnext->next;
                }

            }
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < num_vertices ; i++)
            free(list[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'm still learning. The algorithm isnt working but there aren't any errors.

Comment: If you wan't to check proper use of `malloc` and `free` I recommend [valgrind](http://www.google.co.ve/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvalgrind.org%2F&ei=WTuTVPusL8upNvKdgtAF&usg=AFQjCNHQlvGRULIyRUKZcCGU0LCl3BORew&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY), if you are working with Linux, of course.

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
list[a]->next->val=b;
```

`list[a]->next` maybe `NULL`. IMO, it's better to put a `NULL` check before dereferencing.

Same goes for `ptr->next` in

```
ptr->next->val=b;
```

Nevertheless, you need to allocate memory to `next` before using it. Otherwise, it will point to some 
*unknown* memory location.

Also, why not start the loop from `0` in

```
for(h=1;h<=num_vertices;h++)
```

Sidenote: Please do not cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: `list[a]->next` might not be `NULL`. It is just pointing somewhere random in memory.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you. Updated accordingly.